# Problems attaching a function handle on Matlab to integral expression

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-expressions

I have an integral expression which I defined on Matlab using

```
x = 0:1/1000:1;
g = @(x) (exp(-1./x.^2).*heaviside(x)).*(exp(-1./(1-x).^2).*heaviside(1-x));
t = 0:1/1000:1; 
f = zeros(size(t));
for i = 1:length(t)
    f(i) = integral(g,0,t(i));
end
```

I can plot it, for example, using `plot(t,f)`, but for other purposes I would like to attach a function handle to `f`, i.e. something like `f = @(t) zeros(size(t))`. I have not been able to figure it out thus far. `f = @(t) integral(@(x)g(x),0,t)` is also not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I can't comment yet. But does this work?

```
funcHand= @(t) integral(g,0,t);
```

You don't have to define x in your code above, since the input to `integral` is a function handle.

Then to check it's the same:

```
f2 = zeros(size(t));
for i = 1:length(t)
    f2(i) = funcHand(t(i));
end
```

Whoops, the other answer said all the above (just replaced the for loop with arrayfun. I didn't see it while writing the answer.

**Edit**

If you want to build-in the for loop, try:

```
funcHand= @(t) arrayfun(@(u) integral(g, 0, u),t);
```

And test:

```
plot(funcHand(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately your code also does not work. I get the same errors. Essentially, I want to be able to write `f(t)` in the following lines.

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice.

Comment: I just spelled out your answer... hopefully it answers the Q.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Indeed. It also worked out very nicely, so I'd like to thank both of you. I will delay awarding the "answered" tag, as per the usual Stack Exchange conventions, but Mad Physicist, I hope you won't mind if I award it to Jon...he could perhaps do with the reputation points in any case.

Comment: It does. I think OP didn't read the part about not passing an array into the non-arrayfun version.

Comment: @user3482534. I don't mind at all. Jon came up with the final answer before I did and I would select his answer in your place. I just updated mine for completeness

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
f = @(u) integral(g, 0, u)
```

The additional level of indirection in `g` seems superfluous. Note that I have called the input `u`. Keep in mind that `f` will not accept vectors as its inputs. So doing something like `f(t)` in your current workspace will not create the same array as your for loop is doing. You will have to iterate through the array. The convenience function [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) will do this for you:

```
o = arrayfun(f, t)
```

It is roughly equivalent to the loop you have now:

```
o = zeros(size(t));
for i = 1:length(o)
    o(i) = f(t(i));
end
```

`arrayfun` can actually be incorporated into your function handle to allow it to process vector arguments:

```
h = @(t) arrayfun(f, t)
```

To avoid the proliferation of unnecessary function handles, you can do

```
f = @(t) arrayfun(@(u) integral(g, 0, u), t)
```

Comment: I get errors: `A and B must be floating-point scalars. Error in @(u)integral(g,0,u)`. Would you be able to expand on what you mean by "you will have to iterate through the array"?

Comment: @user3482534. It looks like you are trying to pass in `t` for you. I specifically mentioned that this will be impossible. See my updated solution. Also, @Jon's answer.